# Having Problem changing fraction with Binomial Denominator into a Mixed Expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

Not sure if my workbook is wrong or my calculation. Probably me :)

Here is the problem:

$\frac {k^3-1}{k-1}$

My work:
(inserted some zeros because of my lack of MathJax skills)

$
\begin{array}{r}
\text{}    \underline{k^2+k+1} \\
k-1 | k3 + 0 +0-1  \\
    \underline{k^3-k^2+0-1\phantom{0}} \\
      k^2+0-1 \\
     \underline{k^2-k+0\phantom{0}} \\
     k-1
\\
     \underline{k-1\phantom{0}} \\
     0
\end{array}
$

My answer is: $k^2+k+1$

My workbook gives the answer of: $k^2+k+1+\frac{2}{k-1}$

Which is correct?

Comment: Your answer is correct

Comment: As Jakobian stated, your answer is correct.  It seems the workbook's answer comes from using a numerator of $k^3 + 1$ instead of $k^3 - 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is correct.

Remark:

This is a special case of a famous formula and it is known as [geometric series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricSeries.html).

In general $$1+k +\ldots + k^{n-1} = \frac{k^n-1}{k-1}$$

For your case $n=3$.